# Is it possible to none interactively add a domain name to a Web App

Tags: powershell, azure

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438096/specifying-web-app-domain-name-in-resource-manager-template) question on Stack overflow, because I can't get Azure Resource Manager to assign a domain name via Json

But from doing some research, I can't actually find a way to assign a domain name to a web app in any way other than pointing and clicking through the portal.

I believe I could put a load balancer in front of it, which I think can be done via Powershell. But I feel like I'm missing a point as it seems too big of a concept to simply not be possible. (or maybe I'm just missing the Add-AzureDomainName commandlet ;) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set-AzureWebsite cmdlet:

```
Set-AzureWebsite -Name "mysite" -HostNames @('www.mysite.com', 'mysite.com')
```

**Reference**:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495207.aspx

You don't need to add *.azurewebsites.net domain, in fact, it will not work if you try.

Regarding ARM, I believe if you try again without passing azurewebsites.net it should work but I'm not able to verify this right now.

```
"hostnames": [
    "www.mysite.com", 
    "mysite.com"

  ],
  "enabledHostNames": [
    "www.mysite.com",
    "mysite.com"
  ]
```

Comment: The Powershell command works - thanks! - but ARM gives a message of - 'The hostnames for the site must include the default hostname with dns suffix 'azurewebsites.net'.' (I've logged an MS support call for the ARM issue)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Plz return if you get any answer from MS.